# How to add results value to a tsv file?

Tags: python, file

I'm computing the cosine distance between two textual fields (description and subject) by using a data set in .tsv format.

```
  object  | description  | subject | label  |
----------------------------------------------
 myObject |myDescription |mySubject|mylabel |
```

I'm able to compute the cosine and print the result per each row in my terminal:

```py
with open("excel/dataset.csv.tsv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split("\t")
        mytext = parts[2]
        .........
        def cos_sim(a, b):
           dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
           norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
            norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
           return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

        print(cos_sim(a,b))
```

However, I would like to add a col to my .tsv file reporting per each line the corresponding cosine value.

```
  object  | description  | subject | label  | cosine
----------------------------------------------------
 myObject |myDescription |mySubject|mylabel | 0.1234
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest using Pandas rather than read TSV line by line

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Prepend the original line and a tab to the `print` argument.